# Error after upgrading TypeScript (3->4) and Storybook (5->6)

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, storybook

After upgrading TypeScript from 3.9.6 to 4.4.4 and Storybook from 5.3.19 to 6.5.10, I'm getting the following error in several files:

```
ERROR in ./.storybook/preview.js-generated-config-entry.js
Module build failed (from ../node_modules/@storybook/builder-webpack4/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: /Users/liran.harary/dev/mmservices/site/site-pages-ui/.storybook/preview.js-generated-config-entry.js: 'loose' mode configuration must be the same for @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties, @babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods and @babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object (when they are enabled).
    at enableFeature (/Users/liran.harary/dev/mmservices/site/node_modules/@babel/helper-create-class-features-plugin/lib/features.js:51:13)
    at PluginPass.pre (/Users/liran.harary/dev/mmservices/site/node_modules/@babel/helper-create-class-features-plugin/lib/index.js:82:35)
    at transformFile (/Users/liran.harary/dev/mmservices/site/node_modules/@storybook/builder-webpack4/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/transformation/index.js:97:27)
    at transformFile.next (<anonymous>)
    at run (/Users/liran.harary/dev/mmservices/site/node_modules/@storybook/builder-webpack4/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/transformation/index.js:35:12)
    at run.next (<anonymous>)
    at transform (/Users/liran.harary/dev/mmservices/site/node_modules/@storybook/builder-webpack4/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/transform.js:29:41)
    at transform.next (<anonymous>)
    at step (/Users/liran.harary/dev/mmservices/site/node_modules/@storybook/builder-webpack4/node_modules/gensync/index.js:261:32)
    at /Users/liran.harary/dev/mmservices/site/node_modules/@storybook/builder-webpack4/node_modules/gensync/index.js:273:13
    at async.call.result.err.err (/Users/liran.harary/dev/mmservices/site/node_modules/@storybook/builder-webpack4/node_modules/gensync/index.js:223:11)
 @ multi ../node_modules/@storybook/core-server/node_modules/@storybook/core-client/dist/esm/globals/polyfills.js ../node_modules/@storybook/core-server/node_modules/@storybook/core-client/dist/esm/globals/globals.js ../node_modules/@storybook/builder-webpack4/node_modules/webpack-hot-middleware/client.js?reload=true&quiet=false&noInfo=undefined ./storybook-init-framework-entry.js ../node_modules/@storybook/react/dist/esm/client/preview/config-generated-config-entry.js ./.storybook/preview.js-generated-config-entry.js ./generated-stories-entry.js main[5]
```

Some relevant details:

- I upgraded all our storybook packages manually. I initially tried using Storybook's upgrade script (`npx storybook upgrade`), however it didn't do anything
- I added `Add "skipLibCheck": true` to the "compilerOptions" in the relevant workspace's tsconfig.json
- I also created a *.storybook/main.js* file for Storybook, as I saw it was required in Storybook 6
- I added `loose: true` and `shippedProposals: true` to '@babel/preset-env' in the relevant workspace's babel.config.js (see further below)

Dependencies in the problematic (yarn) workspace:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.10.1",
    "aphrodite": "^2.2.3",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "consent-string": "^1.4.1",
    "current-device": "^0.10.0",
    "iframe-resizer": "^4.3.2",
    "intersection-observer": "^0.7.0",
    "luxon": "^1.22.0",
    "mm-client-core": "1.0.0",
    "mm-theme-configuration": "1.0.0",
    "mm-ui-components": "1.0.0",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "traffic-source-analyzer": "1.0.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.10.2",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.10.1",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining": "^7.16.7",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.10.2",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.10.1",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.10.1",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^5.3.19",
    "@storybook/addon-info": "^5.3.21",
    "@storybook/addon-knobs": "^6.4.0",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.5.10",
    "@storybook/addon-viewport": "^6.5.10",
    "@storybook/addons": "^6.5.10",
    "@storybook/react": "^6.5.10",
    "@types/iframe-resizer": "^3.5.8",
    "@types/luxon": "^1.21.0",
    "@types/nock": "^11.1.0",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.0",
    "@types/storybook__addon-info": "^5.2.4",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^2.10.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^2.10.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.5",
    "core-js": "^3.4.7",
    "enzyme": "^3.7.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.6.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-config-mm": "git+https://github.com/FTBpro/eslint-config-mm.git#v3.1",
    "eslint-loader": "3.0.2",
    "jest": "^24.0.0",
    "jest-junit": "^10.0.0",
    "mm-pilot-mock": "1.0.0",
    "nock": "^11.7.0",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.3",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "^2.2.1",
    "typescript": "4.4.4",
    "webpack": "^4.29.6",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.10",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.4",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.3",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^1.7.2"
  },
}
```

My babel.config.js

```
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true);
  const presets = [
      ['@babel/preset-env',
        {
          modules: false,
          targets: {
            browsers: ['last 2 versions'],
          },
          // Added these to try to solve the error. Didn't help
          loose: true,
          shippedProposals: true,
        },
      ],
      '@babel/preset-react',
    '@babel/preset-typescript',
  ];
  const env = {
    test: {
      presets: [
        ['@babel/preset-env'],
        '@babel/preset-react',
        '@babel/preset-typescript'],
    },
  };

  const plugins = [
    '@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import',
    '@babel/plugin-syntax-import-meta',
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties',
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-json-strings',
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining',
  ];

  return {
    presets,
    env,
    plugins,
  };
};
```

storybook/main.js

```
module.exports = {
  addons: [],
  babel: async (options) => ({
    // Update your babel configuration here
    ...options,
  }),
  framework: '@storybook/react',
  stories: ['../src/**/*.stories.@(js|mdx)'],
  webpackFinal: async (config, { configType }) => {
    // Make whatever fine-grained changes you need
    // Return the altered config
    return config;
  },
};
```

I've tried virtually every possible solution I could find, to no avail. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's your `.babelrc` or `babel.config.js` file look like? I remember this problem and I had to add this to my preset-env preset "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "loose":true,
        "shippedProposals":true
      }
    ]
  ]

Comment: Thanks Adam, just tried that, it didn't help unfortunately (see details in my edit)

Comment: Do you need all those plugins? What happens if you get rid of class properties?

Comment: @Adam That just made the build get stuck. I found a fix in the end, see below. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by adding `{ loose: true }` to the relevant plugin, like so:

*babel.config.js*

```js
module.exports = function (api) {
  const presets = [
      // ...
  ];
  const env = {
    // ...
  };

  const plugins = [
    '@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import',
    '@babel/plugin-syntax-import-meta',
    // This was the fix
    ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties', { loose: true }],
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-json-strings',
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining',
  ];

  return {
    presets,
    env,
    plugins,
  };
};
```